# Selenium Pagefactory click functionality is not working in Safari browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, webdriver, specflow

I have an automation suite that's running successfully in Windows. But I installed visual studio on Mac and tried running the same on MAC Safari Technology Preview browser. It fails to click on a web element

```
FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = ".c-search__btn")]
public IWebElement HeaderSearchButton { get; set; }

HeaderSearchButton.Click();
```

The step gets executed successfully. No errors were thrown. But the corresponding click has not happened. 
Hence I get an exception in the next step.

The same click functionality is working across other browsers.

Any help on how to proceed with the investigation?? Prior to this step, I can enter the search text in the text box without any issue.

Comment: Have you tried using actions or Javascript executor?

Comment: Hi Reezo, I didnt, then i would end up rewriting the entire automation suite just for one browser. The trouble is that I cant customize t script just for one browser. I sense that click command is working , but not sure why Safari Technology preview browser is not reacting after receiving the click.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with :

```
FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "c-search__btn")
```

Comment: Hi, the locators are fine. As mentioned it is working on other browser. but the click event is not happening and I am not seeing any exception as well. Looks like it clicked and proceeded to next step. but unfortunately the browser is not reacting to the click. (Tried class name as well but still the same)